# Parsing nested JSONObject in Android

Tags: android, json

In my project, I am getting the following JSON from the HTTP response.

```
{"base":"USD","date":"2015-04-24","rates":{"AUD":1.2827,"BGN":1.8069,"BRL":2.9733,"CAD":1.2119,"CHF":0.9551,"CNY":6.1948,"CZK":25.364,"DKK":6.8927,"GBP":0.6614,"HKD":7.75,"HRK":7.0284,"HUF":278.53,"IDR":12954.0,"ILS":3.9244,"INR":63.563,"JPY":119.51,"KRW":1078.25,"MXN":15.358,"MYR":3.5741,"NOK":7.8298,"NZD":1.3216,"PHP":44.281,"PLN":3.7076,"RON":4.08,"RUB":51.215,"SEK":8.6674,"SGD":1.3375,"THB":32.55,"TRY":2.7314,"ZAR":12.182,"EUR":0.9239}}
```

I want to get the "BGN" from the above json. How to get it.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple steps involved in this

First: Create a jsonObject

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(yourJSON_String);
```

Second: Get your desired Object or Array, in your case

```
obj =  getJSONObject("rates")
```

Third: Get required String

```
obj.getString("BGN");
```

Here is the [JSON CLASS REFERENCE](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject("<your-string">);
JSONObject ratesJson = responseJson.getJSONObject("rates");
double rate = ratesJson.getDouble("BGN");
```

To see the `JSON` object clearly, use [PrettyJson](http://jsonprettyprint.com/). Copy paste the `JSON` string here and it will show you nested objects (if any) for clearly understanding the response.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using JSONObject, and that your root document is called "doc",

`JSONObject rates = doc.getJSONObject("rates")` would get you the rates part:

`{"AUD":1.2827,"BGN":1.8069,"BRL":2.9733,"CAD":1.2119,"CHF":0.9551,"CNY":6.1948,"CZK":25.364,"DKK":6.8927,"GBP":0.6614,"HKD":7.75,"HRK":7.0284,"HUF":278.53,"IDR":12954.0,"ILS":3.9244,"INR":63.563,"JPY":119.51,"KRW":1078.25,"MXN":15.358,"MYR":3.5741,"NOK":7.8298,"NZD":1.3216,"PHP":44.281,"PLN":3.7076,"RON":4.08,"RUB":51.215,"SEK":8.6674,"SGD":1.3375,"THB":32.55,"TRY":2.7314,"ZAR":12.182,"EUR":0.9239}`

From this object you can then simply get the BGN value using

`String bgn = rates.getString("BGN")`